# ASP.NET Core NPM e webpack/gulp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, npm, gulp, webpack

Criei um projeto no asp.net core usando o template empty (`dotnet new web`).

Pelo que pesquisei, para adicionar pacotes como *Bootstrap* ou *jquery*, temos que usar o NPM, que basicamente é adicionar o `package.json` na raiz do projeto e as chaves básicas.

Utilizando o comando `npm install jquery` e `npm install bootstrap` eu instalo os pacotes que preciso, porém ele cria a pasta `node_modules` e a pasta padrão para as dependências de *javascript* e *css* é a pasta `wwwroot`.

Agora preciso saber como copiar somente os arquivos necessários da pasta `node_modules`, sei que existe o *gulp* e o *webpack* para isso. Porém não tenho conseguido implementar essas ferramentas em meu projeto.

Então minha dúvida é como implementar o `gulp` ou o `webpack` em um projeto `ASP.NET Core`.

E qual deles é mais recomendado utilizar.

Comment: O próprio dotnet new não tem nenhum template que utilize node.js com .net core? Aqui no trabalho não tenho o .net core.

Comment: Teria o template de angular

Comment: Além dos modelos iniciais, você pode instalar novos modelos, você pode consultar alguns no seguinte link [`Available templates for dotnet new`](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new). você pode consultar a lista de templates instalados com o comando `dotnet new -h`

Comment: Tenta utilizar o `dotnet new webapi`. Nesse template você só tem a API que é desacoplada do front-end. Assim você pode trabalhar com o node.js tranquilamente sem se preocupar com o wwwroot.